# how to show min and max value in horizontal manner?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, react-d3-speedometer

I am using `react-d3-speedometer` package for a speedometer. i am able to implement it. but it's max value and minimum value i need to display in horizontal manner. [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-speedometer)

**code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSpeedometer from "react-d3-speedometer";

export default class GaugeChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <React.Fragment>
            <ReactSpeedometer
                maxValue={7000}
                value={7000}
                valueFormat=".1s"
                needleColor="red"
                startColor="#ffc7ba"
                segments={630}
                maxSegmentLabels={1}
                endColor="#FF471A"
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

**current view**

[image]

**expected view**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below style and add in your CSS file

```
 <style>
    text.segment-value:nth-child(1){
          font-size: 16px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: unset !important;
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-105px, 20px); 
     }

        text.segment-value:nth-child(2){
          font-size: 16px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: unset !important;
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(105px, 20px);
        } 

</style>
```

OutPut : https://prnt.sc/q5vvzg

Hope I have clear Your answer!